# docker mysql:latest not using dedicated volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volume, persistent

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    www:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.lamp
        ports: 
            - "${WEBSERVER_PORT}:80"
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www/html/
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - default
    db:
        image: mysql:latest
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD} 
        volumes:
            - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - ./conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
            - mysql_vol:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - default
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        links: 
            - db:db
        ports:
            - ${PHPMYADMIN_PORT}:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            UPLOAD_LIMIT: 64M 
volumes:
    mysql_vol:
        external: false
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite 
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql    

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      git \
      libicu-dev \
      zlib1g-dev \
      g++\
      libpq-dev \
      libmcrypt-dev \
      git \
      zip \
      unzip

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl
```

However, after running "docker compose up -d",
the folder "mysql_vol" stays empty and the result of "docker volume inspect test_project_mysql_vol" yields:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2023-02-15T16:07:08+01:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "test_project",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.15.1",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "mysql_vol"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/test_project_mysql_vol/_data",
        "Name": "test_project_mysql_vol",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

How could it be that, while setting external: false, the mountpoint still is not in the folder as the docker-compose.yml file, but still in /var/lib/docker/volumes?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to refer to a local directory, you need to write `./mysql_vol`:

```
db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports: 
        - "3306:3306"
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD} 
    volumes:
        - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        - ./conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
        - ./mysql_vol:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
        - default
```

If you write `mysql_vol` without the leading `./`, you are referring to a named Docker volume which will be allocated automatically by Docker from its own storage.

The `external` keyword is used when you want to refer to an existing named volume that is not managed by `docker compose`. Setting `external: false` is a no-op because that's the default.

Comment: Thanks! What I want to achieve is having the volume in my host folder, and when using ./mysql_vol rather than a volume, I cannot login. All files are generated in mysql_vol but Icannot authenticate into phpmyadmin.

Comment: That seems like a different issue, and might be worth a separate question.